# Delete rows where all columns (except ID) are NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some big tables with 100-300 columns, and sometimes an item is full of null values, leaving only the ID, like this :

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|     |------------------|
|          ID         |     Column 1     |     Column 2     | ....|    Column 300    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|     |----------------- |
|          1          |      value       |       value      | ....
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       NULL       |        NULL      | ....
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |       NULL       |        NULL      | ....
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

so i want to delete those but the only way i can think of is a large chunk of
 `CASE (colA IS NULL and colB IS NULL AND colC IS NULL ...)`
But that is impractical for me since there are a lot of tables with a lot of columns.

Is there a way to delete every row which, except from the ID column, contains only NULLS?

Comment: You’ll need to use Dynamic SQL for this, I’m afraid.

Comment: Column tribbles ?

Comment: This is what happens when you have a table with 300 columns. You should consider redesigning your db.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this without stating each column in the SQL.  Perhaps the bigger question is why you have so many columns.  100 is probably pushing the max number you should have.

Comment: @jarlh Yeah but its not my own design, i just receive them and process their contents, so i cannot change a thing

Comment: Tough luck. As Dai said, perhaps dynamic SQL is the way.

Comment: I don't know the JSON capabilities of SQL Server, but would something like this work? https://rextester.com/DKDM74048 It converts each row into a JSON value, removing the ID key and all null values. If the result is an empty JSON all columns were null

Comment: Out of sight out of mind?

Answer (score 2):

Just replace with your table and schema:

```
DECLARE @TableSchema SYSNAME
       ,@TableName SYSNAME

SELECT @TableSchema = 'dbo'
      ,@TableName = 'SurveyInstances';

DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = 'DELETE FROM '  + @TableSchema + '.' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' +  STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ' AND ' + [name] + ' IS NULL' 
        FROM [sys].[columns] 
        WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@TableSchema + '.' + @TableName)
            AND [column_id] NOT IN
            (
                SELECT IC.[column_id]
                FROM [sys].[indexes] I
                INNER JOIN [sys].[index_columns] IC
                    ON I.[object_id] = IC.[object_id]
                    AND I.[index_id] = IC.[index_id]
                WHERE I.[is_primary_key] = 1
                    AND I.[object_id] =  OBJECT_ID(@TableSchema + '.' + @TableName)
            )
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,5
    ,''
);

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```

In the above example we are getting the primary key columns (if such exists) in order not to include them in the `WHERE` clause. Then having the columns, just concatenate the `IS NULL` statements and your T-SQL statement is ready.

Comment: @StefanSteiger And why?

Comment: And if the id is not set as primary-key, and there is no index, you'll never delete anything lol  -  and unpredictable behavious if there is a another index on any of the columns that aren't primary-key.  Because you then include the primary key which is not marked as one in the columns you compare with null and concat with AND. And if there's another index, you omit the column the index is on.

Comment: @StefanSteiger The code is pretty simple. Test it, before commenting it.

Comment: DELETE FROM dbo.SurveyInstances WHERE id IS NULL AND name IS NULL AND value1 IS NULL AND value2 IS NULL

Comment: So, if the 4 columns are NULL for particular row, it will be deleted.

Comment: Yea, but if the id isn't because it's a primary key that's not marked as one, then it won't be deleted. Also, clustered doesn't mean it's a primary key. CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_SurveyInstances ON dbo.SurveyInstances(value2);

Comment: I can't see how a the delete statement you have written will no delete row?

Comment: @StefanSteiger OK. I change it to primary key, but it will not work for column store indexes, for example. The main point is the idea - to use system tables to build the query which you need.

Comment: Yea that much is clear. But it isn't even necessary.

Comment: A better way to get the PK columns: 
SELECT kcu.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS tc 
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS kcu 
 ON kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
 AND kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
 AND kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = tc.TABLE_SCHEMA 
 AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = tc.TABLE_NAME 

WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
AND tc.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
AND tc.TABLE_NAME = 'SurveyInstances'

Comment: @StefanSteiger You are missing the point here. In the system views you have all the details you need - if you want exclude columns by Primary Key; if you want - exclude them by name or data type; it's very simple code that can be easily change to match different scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

By far no SQL expert here, but you could transform the table into an XML, mark all NULL valued columns as nil-elements and then filter out all rows which only have nil-elements besides the column id.

```
--Glorious test table with an amazing amount of three columns..
declare @tTable table ([id] int, [c1] varchar(10), [c2] bit);
insert into @tTable values
    (1, 'wayne', null),
    (2, null, 1),
    (3, null, null), --This one goes
    (4, null, 0),
    (5, '', null),
    (7, null, null); --This one goes;

--Transform table to XML marking NULL values with @nil..
declare @tXML xml; set @tXML = (
    select
        *
    from
        @tTable
    for xml path('row'), type, elements xsinil
);

--Removes all [id] contained in the select below..
delete from @tTable where [id] in (
    --Select all [id] which have no element NOT being marked as NULL (=merely NULL values)
    select
        p.value('./id[1]', 'int')
    from
        (select 1 as [wayne]) as [tT]
        cross apply @tXML.nodes('/row') as t(p)
    where
        (
            p.exist('./*[not(local-name(.)="id")][not(@xsi:nil)]') = 0
        )
);

select * from @tTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way is doing it without dynamic SQL, and without any manual selection of a column where all values but id are NULL:

- you said all other columns but id are nullable
- so we insert just an id with value -666 into the source table
  since all fields but id are NULLABLE, this is easy. 
  since autoids create values > 0, you don't get any collision on -666
- we select the -666 id into a temporary table
- we can now delete the -666 entry from the source table
- we drop the id column in the temporary tabe
- we cross join the temporary table to the source table
- we select the id from the source table, and all the fields (null-fields) from the temporary table
- we intersect this null-value-table-with-id with the source table
- we select all the IDs from the intersection table
- and then we delete the rows from the source table by those IDs
- to make sure we don't get an error if the temp table exists (connection pooling), we drop the temp table if it already exists, both in the beginning and the end.
- done
- Note: if your primary key (id) is specified as identity (auto_increment), you'll need to turn `IDENTITY INSERT ON/OFF` before and after the insert statement.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#a') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #a; 

DELETE FROM Foobar WHERE id = -666; 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Foobar ON; -- only if the id field is an IDENTITY
INSERT INTO Foobar(id) SELECT -666 AS id; 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Foobar OFF; -- only if the id field is an IDENTITY


SELECT * 
INTO #a 
FROM Foobar 
WHERE Foobar.id = -666;

ALTER TABLE #a DROP COLUMN id; 
DELETE FROM Foobar WHERE id = -666; 

DELETE FROM Foobar WHERE Foobar.id IN 
(
    SELECT tIntersect.id FROM 
    (
        SELECT * FROM Foobar 

        INTERSECT 

        SELECT 
             Foobar.id 
            ,tNullValues.* 
        FROM Foobar 
        CROSS JOIN #a AS tNullValues 
    ) AS tIntersect  
); 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#a') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #a;
```

Note that intersect will fail if you have a column of type xml, text, geography or hierarchyid. Also, note that SQL-server doesn't implement INTERSECT ALL, so this only works reliably if your table has a primary key (respectively only if you have at least one non-nullable column with a unique id - a primary key ensures that, but the column doesn't necessarely have to be defined as primary key).

---

**Old more complex variant:**

---

You could do this with INTERSECT:

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Foobar
(
    id int NOT NULL,
    nam varchar(50) NULL
)
```

Enter a few values with id and name, and a few with just ids

Then do:

```
DECLARE @maxId as integer 
SET @maxId = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Foobar);


;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS i 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT i+1 AS i 
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE CTE.i < @maxId 
)



SELECT 
     id 
    ,nam 
FROM Foobar 

INTERSECT 

SELECT 
     i AS id 
    ,CAST(NULL AS varchar(50)) AS nam 
FROM CTE 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

This yields the id values of all rows that you want to delete.

Then you can do this:

```
DECLARE @maxId as integer 
SET @maxId = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Foobar);


;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS i 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT i+1 AS i 
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE CTE.i < @maxId 
)


DELETE FROM Foobar WHERE id IN 
(
    SELECT id FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
             id 
            ,nam 
        FROM Foobar 

        INTERSECT 

        SELECT 
             i AS id 
            ,CAST(NULL AS varchar(50)) AS nam 
        FROM CTE 
    ) AS t 
)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

---

Or you can generate the list of columns dynamically:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ORDINAL_POSITION = 1 THEN ' CAST(NULL AS ' + DATA_TYPE + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
        ELSE ',CAST(NULL AS ' + DATA_TYPE + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
    END 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Foobar' 
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
```

And using this, you can get the primary-key columns, so you can exclude them from the column-list:

```
SELECT kcu.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS tc 
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS kcu 
    ON kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    AND kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
    AND kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = tc.TABLE_SCHEMA 
    AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = tc.TABLE_NAME 

WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
AND tc.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
AND tc.TABLE_NAME = 'Foobar'
```

Comment: _since autoids create values > 0_ Only by conventional use. It is trivially easy to add an identity column that starts at a negative number or that uses a negative increment value. Careful what you assume. And starting an identity column at 1 effectively "loses" half the domain of the numeric datatype involved.

Comment: @SMor: I know. But I've never seen somebody actually doing that. True, that doesn't mean that this case doesn't exist, but it's the most likely scenario for most readers of this post, like 95% certain. And the rest of the 5% is probably/hopefully able to think that far. Also, using identity-insert, the value could have been manually inserted, independent of start-value and increment step size. But for the case of failure, you'd have to wrap this into a transaction anyway.

Comment: @Lain: Oh, I didn't see that you posted it - removed it - got an upvote from me ;)

Comment: Using `INTERSECT` or `Recursive CTE` - this can be very slow with large datasets and can't beat the simplicity and performance of dynamic T-SQL statement;

Answer (score 1):

Here's my way to "trick" the engine into doing this:

1) **Manually** find an ID with all columns nulls. Let's say you find hits to be ID=56. All rows of this table except ID should have nulls.Put this into a temptable:

```
select * 
into #a
from yourtable 
where ID=56
```

2) Drop the ID column from that table. Only the null columns remain.

```
alter table #a drop column ID
```

3) Create all *possibly* unneeded rows by using a cartesian product of ids and the temp table. 
Then, have this removed from your original table using EXCEPT:

```
    select * from yourtable
except
    select t.ID,#a.*
        from yourtable t
        cross join #a
```

Comment: Aint the time required to manually find such a row as quick as to just find all of them with simply copy-pasting 'where is null' statements or how do you manually find one?

Comment: Good point. I arbitrarily assumed that *most* of the rows are like that, so you could find one with just a `select *`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run below query for your requirement. It will delete all rows having NULL values(Except ID) COLUMN

```
DECLARE @TSchema SYSNAME
       ,@TName SYSNAME

SELECT @TSchema = 'dbo'
      ,@TName = 'yourTableName';

DECLARE @TSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @TSQLStatement = 'DELETE FROM '  + @TSchema + '.' + @TName + ' WHERE ' +  STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ' AND ' + [name] + ' IS NULL' 
        FROM [sys].[columns] 
        WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@TSchema + '.' + @TName)
            AND [column_id] NOT IN
            (
                SELECT IC.[column_id] FROM [sys].[indexes] I
                INNER JOIN [sys].[index_columns] IC ON I.[object_id] = IC.[object_id]
             AND I.[index_id] = IC.[index_id]
                WHERE I.[type] = 1
                    AND I.[object_id] =  OBJECT_ID(@TSchema + '.' + @TName)
            )AND name <> 'id'
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,5
    ,''
);

EXEC sp_executesql @TSQLStatement;
```

Feel free for any query.

Comment: So, you basically copy-paste, change few variables names and add `AND name<> 'id'`? Great work.

Comment: @gotqn: And not only that, he also didn't remove the not-in, which becomes superfluous.

Comment: @StefanSteiger Superfluous will be to test a column to be NULL, if by definition it is always NOT NULL being part of primary key.