# How to delete rows where most columns are empty in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL, so please forgive if this question is dumb.

I have a table with 800 columns. I want to delete all rows in which > 400 columns are null. How do I do that?

Comment: Here is a similar answer but for Sql Server (not postgres): https://stackoverflow.com/a/58320834/1260204. I am not familiar with postgres *but* if you can query the schema and then use that to create a dynamic statement with `sum` clauses (1 per column) where if the value is null use 1 otherwise use 0 then if the total sum is greater than 400 delete it should be possible without having to hardcode all the column names.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to covert the entire row plus non-null const to a JSON-like string and count the number of `'":null,'` substrings. I assume `id` is a key so this will return a number of NULLs for `id`

```
create table foo (
    id int,
    c1 int,
    c2 int
);

insert into foo 
  values
  (1,10, 5),
  (2,null,15)
;

select id, (char_length(c) - char_length(REPLACE(c, '":null,', ''))) / char_length('":null,') cnt
from (
  select  id, json_agg(t)::text c
  from (
    select *, 1
    from foo
  ) t
  group by id
) t
order by id
```

Returns

```
id  cnt
1   0
2   1
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, is to use `num_nulls()` function:

```
delete from wide_table
where num_nulls(col1, col2, col3, col4, ...., col800) > 400;
```

As you only have to write the number of columns once, this should be the easiest way to do it. Typically graphical SQL clients will help you auto-complete the column names, so that you don't have to type them out manually.

---

If you don't want to type the column names (or your SQL client doesn't support it), you can use some JSON transformations to get the number of non-null values:

```
select *
from wide_table wt
where jsonb_array_length(jsonb_path_query_array(jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(wt)), '$.*')) <= 400
```

`jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(wt))` will generate a JSON value with all keys (=column names) removed where the value (=column values) are NULL. So that only contains the non-null values. `jsonb_path_query_array(..., '$.*')` then builds an array of those non-null values and `jsonb_array_length` counts the number.

Note that the condition needs to be inverted because `jsonb_array_length()` returns the number of **non**-null values.